# Windows Bat Del old files

Tags: batch-file

i have writing a window batch to del the files order than 3 months in some directory, however, there are some problem on :Loop_Folder_Del_Old_Files. I don't know why i cannot assign the last modified date of the files, please help to find out the problem. Below are the source code and program result, thanks!

**Source Code**

```
:program_start
@ECHO ON
echo program_start

:Parameter_Settings
set filePath=c:\New Folder
set delPeriod=3
echo %date%
set curYYYY=%date:~10,4%
set curMM=%date:~7,2%
set curDD=%date:~4,2%

:Set_The_Date_Of_3_Months_Ago
set /A curMM=curMM - %delPeriod%
if &quot;%curMM%&quot; LEQ &quot;0&quot; (
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; set /A curMM=&quot;(curMM + 12 - %delPeriod%)%%12&quot;
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
if %curMM% == 0 (set curMM=12) ELSE (set curMM=%curMM%)
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; set /A curYYYY=curYYYY - 1
)
set curMM=00%curMM%
set curMM=%curMM:~-2%

set curDate=%curYYYY%%curMM%%curDD%

:Loop_Folder_Del_Old_Files
for %%a IN (&quot;%filePath%\*.*&quot;) DO (
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; set ltdate=%%~ta
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; set fileDate=%ltdate:~6,4%%ltdate:~3,2%%ltdate:~0,2%
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; if &quot;%fileDate%&quot; LSS &quot;%curDate%&quot; Del /Q &quot;%%a&quot;
)
:end
echo program end
pause
```

**Result**

C:\>echo program_start
program_start

C:\>set filePath=c:\New Folder

C:\>set delPeriod=3

C:\>echo Fri 22/11/2013
Fri 22/11/2013

C:\>set curYYYY=2013

C:\>set curMM=11

C:\>set curDD=22

C:\>set /A curMM=curMM - 3

C:\>if "8" LEQ "0" (
set /A curMM="(curMM + 12 - 3)%12"
 if 8 == 0 (set curMM=12 )  ELSE (set curMM=8 )
 set /A curYYYY=curYYYY - 1
)

C:\>set curMM=008

C:\>set curMM=08

C:\>set curDate=20130822

C:\>for %a IN ("c:\New Folder*.*") DO (
set ltdate=%~ta
 set fileDate=~6,4%ltdate:~3,2%ltdate:~0,2
 if "" LSS "20130822" Del /Q "%a"
)

C:\>(
set ltdate=22/11/2013 05:36 PM
 set fileDate=~6,4%ltdate:~3,2%ltdate:~0,2
 if "" LSS "20130822" Del /Q "c:\New Folder\New Text Document (2).txt"
)

C:\>(
set ltdate=22/11/2013 05:36 PM
 set fileDate=~6,4%ltdate:~3,2%ltdate:~0,2
 if "" LSS "20130822" Del /Q "c:\New Folder\New Text Document.txt"
)

C:\>echo program end
program end

C:\>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Can we use PowerShell? This would be, IMHO, easier to write and easier to maintain in PowerShell. Modern Windows systems come with PowerShell already.

Comment: To format code, simply hilight the code and press the `{}`

Comment: Where did the HTML come from?

Comment: @foxi OP's brave attempt at formatting. Batch code carried the same structures until a concerned editor went beyond the call...:)

Answer (score 1):

maybe the use of `forfiles` to delete old files could be better in handle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **enable delayed expansion** to make your variables work inside the `for` loop.

Add

```
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your bat file

and then, refer to the variable using the `!var!` syntax *(instead of  `%var%`)*

```
 if "!fileDate!" LSS "!curDate!" Del /Q "%%a"
```

Comment: @MC ND Thank for your comment,however, it doesn't work and show below result after using your recommendation:C:\>(
set ltdate=25/11/2013 05:00 PM
 set fileDate=~6,4%ltdate:~3,2%ltdate:~0,2
 if "!fileDate!" LSS "!curDate!" Del /Q "c:\New Folder\New Text Document.txt"
)

Comment: @user3030364: Maybe you are refering to the answer of @PA. Any way, If as said, you have added `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start of your code, what you have not done is to change the sintax inside the for loop. It needs to be `set fileDate=!ltdate:~6,4!!ltdate:~3,2!!ltdate:~0,2!`, no `%`, use `!` to use delayed expansion and get the correct value of the variable inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Further to `PA`'s correct response,

```
set /A curMM=curMM - %delPeriod%
if "%curMM%" LEQ "0" (
        set /A curMM="(curMM + 12 - %delPeriod%)%%12"
        if %curMM% == 0 (set curMM=12) ELSE (set curMM=%curMM%)
        set /A curYYYY=curYYYY - 1
)
```

Is unreliable as `currMM` may be `08` or `09` which would generate a syntax-error as batch assumes that any numeric starting with `0` is **OCTAL**.

```
set /A curMM=1%curMM% - 100 - %delPeriod%
if %curMM% LEQ 0 (
        set /A curMM=curMM + 12
        set /A curYYYY=curYYYY - 1
)
```

is better. The comparison is executed against the NUMERIC value, not a string value. The value of `curMM` would be 0 for Dec, -1 for Nov, etc - so simply adding 12 and subtracting 1 from the year is sufficient and clearer.